# How can I download Appropriate Chromedriver in Protractor using Webdriver-Manager

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I have designed a cucumber-protractor based automation framework where everything is working fine except for the Webdriver-manager. I need to update the binaries manually each time the IT Department updates google chrome version.

When i use command `"webdriver-manager update --proxy=http://someproxy.com:PORT#"`, webdriver-manager always downloads the latest chromdriver binaries instead of a compatible version as per the current Chrome Version.

Please help me if there is a way to determine the chrome version automatically and download the corresponding Chrome binaries.

I have tried to search for similar behavior and forums elsewhere but none of the commands work. Instead it always downloads the latest version of chromedriver binaries instead of a compatible one.

Please help with some sample code in-case you come through a solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

You could run a `sh` prior to starting your tests that will determine wether the `chromedriver` needs to be updated:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get existing chromedriver version
EXISTING_CD_VERSION=$(node_modules/.bin/chromedriver -version | egrep -o '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)')

# get installed Google Chrome version
CHROME_VERSION=$(/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version | egrep -o '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)')

if [ "$EXISTING_CD_VERSION" = "$CHROME_VERSION" ]; then
    echo "ChromeDriver version matches the Google Chrome version"
else
    NEW_CD_VERSION=$(curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$CHROME_VERSION)
    node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome $NEW_CD_VERSION
fi
```

NOTE: The script above is getting the Google Chrome version from a MacOS system. If you're on Linux, you need to change that to `google-chrome --version`

Comment: omg... I wanted to write similar shell a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/blob/legacy/docs/versions.md

```
webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome  87.0.4280.88
```

you can use --versions.chrome to specify the driver version

Comment: Thanks for the answer @PDHide but what I was asking if there's a failsafe way to determine the installed chrome version automatically and then download corresponding chromedriver binaries like this https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
For protractor

Comment: @SiddharthMishra what os are you using

Comment: I am using Windows for local run however in CI Mode it would be linux containers.

Comment: @SiddharthMishra which images are you using

Comment: google-chrome --version as mentioned in above answer you can use this command to get chrome version and store it a variable like export a = google-chrome --version , and then pass that varaible to webdriver manager

Comment: @SiddharthMishra did you get any solution like you were searching github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager for protractor. Do let me know if you found any.

Comment: @DevRaj - Instead of the same i bundled a specific version of chrome-headless with my framework so that i don't need to update the drivers. This helped me package the framework efficiently as well.

Answer (score 0):

what you actually need to do is to match a version of your local chrome to the version of chromedriver. So

First, find out what your version of chrome is. From example it is `86.0.4240.111`

Then, find out what chromedriver version can be used. Take the major version of the browser (first 3 numbers, `86.0.4240` in our case) and find the corresponding version of the driver by going to this url [https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_${CHROME_VERSION}](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$%7BCHROME_VERSION%7D) (put the major browser version instead of ${CHROME_VERSION}). You'll see the chromedriver you're looking for is `86.0.4240.22`

then just update webdriver specifying the desired version of chromedriver

`webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome $VERSION`

Make sure to put `86.0.4240.22` instead of `$VERSION`

---

But it maybe tricky here because there are 2 installation of protractor usually:

- local
- global

and each has it's own webdriver-manager. So make sure you're updating the right one

Thus you may need to go to it's folder and **from that folder** run `npm i webdriver-manager@latest` and then `node ./bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false`

when you updated the right webdriver, install the right chromedriver like so

`node ./bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome $VERSION`