# E/launcher - session not created: This version of Chrome Driver only supports Chrome version 93 while running protractor tests

Tags: node.js, protractor

I try to run the protractor tests but I encountered an error:

```
[14:14:42] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:14:42] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[14:14:44] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
Current browser version is 92.0.4515.107 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
  (Driver info: chromedriver=93.0.4577.15 (660fc11082ba57405eca2e8c49c3e1af756fbfae-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#203}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 895 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KTUDS3A', ip: '192.168.0.25', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[14:14:44] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
Current browser version is 92.0.4515.107 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
  (Driver info: chromedriver=93.0.4577.15 (660fc11082ba57405eca2e8c49c3e1af756fbfae-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#203}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 895 milliseconds
```

Tried to change the driver version to 92 using `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 92.0.4515.107` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397086/protractor-2-5-4-e-launcher-session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver) but with no luck, the error still exists.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

your chrome is 92, chromedriver is 93. You need to match them.

First try upgrading your chrome. If by the time you try chrome v93 is not out,  you need to downgrade your chromdriver version. For more info go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65585501/9150146)